# Angular-ui bootstrap don't work correctly with templates

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use angular-ui-bootstrap popover. I manually changed template of popover to support html in it. I changed ng-bind to ng-bind-html:

`<div class=\"popover-content\" ng-bind-html=\"content\"></div>`

I'm passing such template to `popover` attribute:

`<span ng-click="scopeFunction()">{{somethingFromScope}}</span>`

So `{{somethingFromScope}}` resolves and works, but `ng-click` function doesn't work. `ng-show`, `ng-if` (looks like any ng- directive) don't work as well.

What's the reason of it? How can I make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just changing template is not enough

Update module dependencies like this:

```
  angular.module('ui.bootstrap.popover', ['ui.bootstrap.tooltip', 'ui.bootstrap.bindHtml'])
```

And change template

```
  <div class="popover-content" bind-html-unsafe="content"></div>
```

Works with angular.ui.bootstrap v0.11.0 from 2014-05-01

Comment: @n8m after thinking about your question again, the only real option to have is to copy modal directive from ui.bootstrap and apply popover styling to it. Or even copy popover template and include that layout into your parent directive conditionally showing and hiding it, you may also use $position service from ui.bootstrap to position your own popover right way.

Comment: But why expression in double brackets evaluated, but ng-directives don't work?

Answer (score 0):

After researching a lot I find a solution:

If you need popover with template - use AngularStrap popover ;)